# Displayed reasons for declined flags

Tags: support, flagging

When I go through my list of flags, I see four different messages to those that were declined:

> 1. *"Declined"*
> 2. *"Declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"*
> 3. *"Declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"*
> 4. *"Declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"*

**What do each of the four messages mean?**

Comment: Am I missing something? Is "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it" unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For queries that are generally about how Stack Exchange works, please first search on meta.stackexchange.com - you will find this one explained there in various posts ages ago. You could start with [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167788/154443).

But to be honest, each one of those reasons is exactly what it says. 2, 3 and 4 are distinctly different. I'm unsure exactly when 1 happens, but there will be a meta.se post that explains it.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a step back for a moment, if you have so many declined flags that you are getting familiar with particular decline reasons, you are probably flagging too many things!

It is good to flag when you see an obvious and prominent problem, but only if you are 99% sure that it's something that's going to help the moderators do their job.

Just as a reference point - in my time here, I have flagged more than 40 things, and only one was declined.

> What do each of the four messages mean?

All the messages are very general, so I would recommend looking at each message in the context of the particular declined flag and trying to understand what the moderator was trying to tell you. For example, if you saw *"Declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"*, perhaps it's because you raised a flag on something that (in the moderator's opinion) wasn't an obviously wrong answer.

Sometimes these things will be a matter of opinion. The question to ask yourself is "Am I really helping the moderators by flagging this?"